# ¿Porque no ejecuta las validacion que le asigne

Tags: c#

```
public static int ValidarUsuarios(Constructor_Login add)
    {



        int Admin = 3;
        int Gerente = 1;
        int Empleado = 2;


        int retorno = 0;


        int nevel = 0;
        MySqlCommand actusuario = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE tipoUsuarios_idtipoUsuarios='" + Admin + "' AND usuario='" + Constructor_Login.usuario + "'"), conexion.obtenerconexion());
        nevel = Convert.ToInt32(actusuario.ExecuteScalar());
        if ( nevel != 3)

        {
            Constructor_Login.nivel = "Administrador";
            MessageBox.Show("Adminnistrador"+Constructor_Login.nivel);

        }
        else
        {

            actusuario = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE tipoUsuarios_idtipoUsuarios='" + Empleado + "' AND usuario='" + Constructor_Login.usuario + "'"), conexion.obtenerconexion());
            nevel = Convert.ToInt32( actusuario.ExecuteScalar());
            if (Empleado != 2)
            {
                Constructor_Login.nivel = "Empleado";
                MessageBox.Show("Empleado" + Constructor_Login.nivel);
            }
            else
            {

                actusuario = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE tipoUsuarios_idtipoUsuarios='" + Constructor_Login.nivel + "' AND usuario='" + Gerente + "'"), conexion.obtenerconexion());
                nevel = Convert.ToInt32(actusuario.ExecuteScalar());
                if (Gerente != 1)
                {
                    Constructor_Login.nivel = "Geremte";
                    MessageBox.Show("Gerente"+Constructor_Login.nivel);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("no se encontro el nivel de usuario", "Error de Sesión", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                return retorno;
            }
            return retorno;
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Comment: Por un lado, deberías ser un poco más explícito de cual es tu problema, sino es prácticamente imposible ayudarte, por otro lado, nunca, JAMAS concatenes un `string` que va a ser usado para una query. Siempre usa `MySQLCommand.Parameters...` Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, estas definiendo los tipos de usuario como un entero. Si `idtipoUsuarios` es un entero, tu consulta es erronea ya que estas pasandole el tipo como un `string`. Trata de quitarle las comillas simples a la query

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! De que validaciones hablas? podrias ser mas claro en donde tenes el problema?

Answer (score -2):

Detecto dos cosas:

- debes usar siempre parametros, no se concatena usando el `string.Format()`, como esto

  ```
  string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios WHERE tipoUsuarios_idtipoUsuarios= ?tipo AND usuario= ?usuario";
  MySqlCommand actusuario = new MySqlCommand(query, conexion.obtenerconexion());
  actusuario.Parameters.AddWithValue("?tipo", Admin);
  actusuario.Parameters.AddWithValue("?usuario",  Constructor_Login.usuario);

  nevel = Convert.ToInt32(actusuario.ExecuteScalar());
  ```

usando el `AddWithValues()` del `Parameters` para asignar los datos

- si usas el `ExecuteScalar()` convirtiendo a numerico tienes que retornar un valor numerico, por eso en el ejemplo lo cambie por `COUNT(*)`

Comment: porque votan negativo, no consideran que usar parametro sea una buena practica de desarrollo? que deba recomendarse siempre, al votar negativo estan desaprobandolo, sino resuelve la pregunta al menos dejenlo sin votar nada, una explicacion como esta no se puede realizar como comentario